# sRGB vs bits per component

Tags: opengl

OpenGL defines the following internal formats for sRGB color space:

```
GL_SRGB
GL_SRGB8
GL_SRGB_ALPHA
GL_SRGB8_ALPHA8
```

Could you please explain why there are no sRGB/sRGBA equivalents for formats with other bits precision, for example `RGB4` or `RGB16` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They don't exist because they're unnecessary.

sRGB can be thought of as a form of compression. By using colors in the sRGB colorspace, you can use the 8-bits-per-component more efficiently, as it essentially distributes more bits to the lighter areas of your scene. If you're using 16-bits-per-component, such compression is unnecessary; you have plenty of bits of precision.

But the deeper reason has to do with hardware implementation. When a GPU reads data from a texture via a texture fetch operation (say, GLSL's `texture` function), it needs to do some conversion of those texel values to useful values within the shader. RGBA8 stores unsigned normalized integers, so it must map the [0, 255] data to the [0, 1.0] floating-point range. That's easily done with a few bitwise operations.

Converting sRGB colorspace values to the [0, 1.0] linear range is much more complicated. But there's an easy way out: a simple lookup table. After all, at 8-bits-per-component, you only need 256 entries.

But if you had to support 16-bits-per-component sRGB, you'd need 65'536 entries. That's a lot more. And given the point above, it's just not worthwhile.

As for the smaller component formats, there's just no point. Such formats are a form of compression; you would never use them if you weren't trying to save storage. But we have *better* forms of image compression: the various block compression formats. They provide for better image compression (4bpp or less, relative to 32bpp), better image *quality* compared to 16bpp, or both.

And they already support sRGB. So there's no reason to provide this functionality for inferior compressed formats.

Comment: So why are there non-sRGB small and big formats like RGBA4?

Comment: @user253751: Because they predate block compressed formats and hardware supports them for compatibility reasons.

Comment: I'm pretty sure RGBA4 is useful in some situations where block-compressed formats are not. Why is it impossible that sRGBA4 is also useful in some situations where block-compressed formats are not?

Comment: @user253751: Maybe, but most of those (already few) uses aren't treating the image as storing *colors*. As such, using the sRGB colorspace wouldn't be appropriate. Can you name a use-case where the sRGB colorspace is appropriate but block compression is not?

Comment: minecraft-style pixel art?

Comment: @user253751: Why would it need to be limited to 4bpp? If you need to have low color resolution but also higher-precision linear color values, you could accomplish the same thing with palettes. After all, you're not doing filtering, which is the main problem with shader-based palettes.

Comment: well if we go in that direction, there is no need for more than one texture format (probably sRGBA8)

Comment: @user253751: You were talking about an extremely specific and isolated scenario, which has a perfectly adequate solution without using a 4-bpc format. My overall point is that we can do just fine without such formats, as they are only useful in esoteric circumstances where we have other, perfectly adequate, options.

Comment: and my point is that there are plenty of texture formats for maximum flexibility, they are not artificially restricted to the ones that "might be useful"

Comment: @user253751: OK, so where is the RGB20105 format? Or maybe the RGB10F20UI10I format? Image formats have never been about "maximum flexibility". They've always been a compromise between hardware implementation, general utility, and backwards compatibility. RGBA4 still exists *only* because of backwards compatibility, not because implementer want to be "maximally flexible".

Comment: GPUs already have 4-bit-channel hardware and also sRGB hardware. Also, not every piece of hardware supports every OpenGL-defined format.

Comment: @user253751: "*GPUs already have 4-bit-channel hardware and also sRGB hardware*" That doesn't mean these two things have any connection to each other. Consider what I said in my answer about how that "sRGB hardware" likely works. "*not every piece of hardware supports every OpenGL-defined format*" No, but GL_RGBA4 is on the list of formats that GPUs are required to support *exactly* as defined (though this was only added in GL 4.1).

Comment: And GL_SRGBA4 would not be on that list.

Comment: @user253751: Also, do note that Vulkan requires that you query whether hardware supports a format or not, so Vulkan has a whole bunch of possible, even esoteric, formats. But there is no `R4G4B4A4_SRGB` that you even *can* query. All of their `SRGB` are 8-bit-per-channel, unsigned normalized. They even have weird ones like `R8_SRGB`. So if Vulkan doesn't even let you *ask the question*, that's a good indicator that hardware isn't designed to do it.

Comment: These are all rationalizations.

Comment: @user253751: This question is about why a thing doesn't exist. These are the reasons why it doesn't exist: it's pointless, it's not supported in hardware, and there are better alternatives. You can like or dislike those reasons. You can disagree with them. But they still *are the reasons*.